# how to get the result of two controller on ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I want to get the values of the two object in thesame ng-repeat

```js
$http.get('/api/PreviewPayroll').success(function (data){
    //alert(data[0].empID);
    $scope.allowance = data;
});

$http.get('/api/Deduction').success(function (data){
    //alert(data[0].empID);
    $scope.Deduction = data;
});
```

```js
<tr ng-repeat="item in allowance && ng-repeat="value in Deduction">
    <td>{{ item.empID }}</td>
    <td>{{ value.empID }}</td>
</tr>
```

how can I get the two scope object on thesame ng-repeat

Comment: If you want to repeat over two lists, then combine the lists into one! will be something like `[ { deduction: ...., allowance: .... }, .... ]` then `ng-repeat="item in list"` and then `item.deduction.empID` or `item.allowance.empID`

Comment: Note that title is misleading. These are 2 `$http` requests not 2 controllers

Comment: Using those get request from the angularJS how can make them an object array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you will want to combine the data.

You can use `$q.all(promises)`:

```
var promise1 = $http.get('/api/PreviewPayroll');

var promise2 = $http.get('/api/Deduction');

$q.all([promise1, promise2]).then(function (results) {
    var allowances = results[0];
    var deductions = results[1];

    var combinedList = /* some combination logic */;
});
```

By using `$q.all()` you are ensuring you have both lists of data before trying to combine anything. You can easily play around with this to get the desired effect. For example, if you don't care if the other list isn't available.

Then you can use the `ng-repeat` in order to iterate over that new combined list:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in combinedList">
    <td>{{ item.allowance.empID }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.deduction.empID }}</td>
</tr>
```

The sub properties `allowance` and `deduction` are based on your combined list.

### However

It is in my honest opinion that, the server side gives you the data in the format you need to display it in. (i.e. the business logic remains server side in a controlled environment). I believe the view should only deal with view logic, like button actions etc..

But this is my opinion, and is what I find easiest.

### Another note

I prefer to also keep the view logic in the JavaScript, hence why I combine the data there. Rather than trying to do some overly complicated angular expression in the HTML.

Comment: `$q.all([promise1, promise2])`...arg is array or hash of promises, not multiple args

Comment: how can I get the values of the results
$q.all([promise1, promise2]).then(function (results) {
        var allowances = results[0];
        var deductions = results[1];
        alert(results[0].empID + " " + results.empID)
    });

the alert result is always undefined can you please help

Comment: do `console.log(arguments)` in the promise to see what has been given to the function....

Answer (score 0):

You could either have a nested `ng-repeat` and also combine the `two objects` into one.

```
 <table>
  <tbody ng-repeat="row in mainCombinedObject">
    <tr>
      <th>{{row.empID}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="sub in row.subObject">
      <td>{{sub.empID}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Combine `$scope.allowance` and  `$scope.Deduction` to one list of objects `"combined"` then do your `ng-repeat`:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="c in combined">
        <td>{{ c.someField }}</td>
        <td>{{ c.someOtherField }}</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Combine them where? Missing an important part of this issue

Comment: Details is up to OP's requirements

Comment: That has nothing to do with it. There are 2 separate `$http` requests and you aren't addressing that issue

Answer (score -1):

You can't do that in such way! If your allowance and Deduction have the same size you have to mix them in the collection like this:

```
var array = [
    { allowance: value1, Deduction: value2},
    { allowance: value3, Deduction: value4},
    ...
];
```

and them use it in the view:

```
    <tr ng-repeat="item in array">
        <td>{{ item.allowance.empID }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.Deduction.empID }}</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Using those get request from the angularJS how can make them an object array